# Cast to array VS is_array()

Tags: php, arrays, performance, casting

Does anyone know of any issues, performance or other, that can occur by casting a variable to an array instead checking it first?

```
// $v could be a array or string
$v = array('1','2','3');
```

OR

```
$v = '1';
```

instead of:

```
if (is_array($v)) foreach ($v as $value) {/* do this */} else {/* do this */}
```

I've started to use:

```
foreach((array) $v as $value) {
    // do this
}
```

It stops the repetition of code quite a bit - but performance is on my mind, not ugly code.

Also, does anyone know how php handles casting an array to an array? No errors are thrown but does the php engine check if it's a array, then return a result before doing the cast process?

Comment: Where does `$v` come from? If it as another function, you should the output consistent and *always* return an array.

Comment: This is an interesting way of handling that situation, I've never thought of that ! Thanks for the idea, I'm interested in the results. You could do a benchmark yourself though.

Comment: Felix Kling, It was more of a general question/theory tbh. I was reading some old code, where unfortunately return types are not consistant (:S crazy i kno). Thank you for the reply :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Never let performance influence your coding style!

Casting to an array allows to some nice tricks, when you need an array, but want to allow a single value

```
$a = (array) "value"; // => array("value")
```

Note, that this may lead to some unwanted (or wanted, but different) behaviours

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->foo = 'bar';
$a = (array) $a; // => array("foo" => "bar");
```

However, this one

```
if(is_array($v)) {
  foreach($v as $whatever) 
  {
    /* .. */
  }
} else {
  /* .. */
}
```

allows you to decide what should happen for every single type, that can occur. This isn't possible, if you cast it "blindly" to an array.

In short: Just choose the one, that better fits the needs of the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I completly agree with you, as long as it doesnt cause a system melt down lol

Comment: Checking if the variable is an array, only by casting it, can still be done. You just need to compare: $v===(array)$v. Taking into consideration the bellow benchmark as well as the loss of readability that comes with casting... I will always use is_array().

Comment: When developing your coding style, you absolutely should take performance into consideration. It should not be your main concern but when all other things are equal, you should go with the more performant option. In this case, I'd say the use of casting is probably more performant and (more importantly) more legible. It reduces repetition and cognitive load and (probably) casting is cheaper than calling `is_array()`

Answer (score 3):

As Felix Kling says above, the best solution is to have your data come from a source that guarantees its type.  However, if you can't do that, here's a comparison for 1000000 iterations:

```
check first: 2.244537115097s
just cast:   1.9428250789642s
```

([source](http://pastebin.com/Knjcyc5X))

Just casting without checking (using `in_array`) seems to be (slightly) quicker.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose less function overhead is the cause. but then again im not to good at reading into benchmarks or how the php engine does things. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveJ314 I presume that the cast operation does `is_array` internally, so doing it manually causes it to be done twice.

Comment: Even if the cast operation used `is_array` internally, it would still only be done once at the most either way - casting *or* calling `is_array()`. Interesting benchmark results though, I expect that the simple minor overhead of calling a php function may cause it to be slower using `is_array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option here is this (this can be done inline as well, of course, to avoid the function call):

```
function is_array($array) {
      return ($array."" === "Array");
}
```

This seems to be slightly faster than is_array, but your mileage may vary.

The problem with casting to an array like this (which is also an option)

```
if ((array) $v === $v)
```

Is that it's faster than is_array for small arrays, but disastrously slower for large ones.

Comment: The breakeven point for using a typecast for type checking is around 200 entries, so it definitely has its place.

Comment: Found this question years later and then I ran two tests on 3v4l with a fairly big array. Using [is_array()](https://3v4l.org/XYicD/perf#output) is faster [than cast-to-array](https://3v4l.org/pGg5S/perf#output) on PHP 5.6. On PHP 7 an onwards it's considerably faster