# PHP / is_array() ternary: return array / create array

Tags: php, return, ternary

Is there any way to achieve something like this without repeating the variable / without packing the whole thing in a function?

So instead of...

```
$data = array();
$result = (is_array($data) ? $data : array());
```

Something like this...

```
$data = array();
$result = (is_array($data) ? return : array());
```

Comment: No, there's no shortcut that automatically returns the argument to the condition function.

Comment: @Barmar So theres absolutely no way to imitate the PHP behaviour of the ($var ?? null)-shortcut, unless the PHP developers introduce such a feature themselves?

Comment: Right, they would have to add a special syntax for 1-argument functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, there is no vanilla PHP construct that does this.

Normalizing input data is a common pattern with code that lives in a generic function where the ability to call it with arguments of varying types is intentional.  In this specific case you could try simply casting `$data` to an array, though [this doesn't work in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127109/4468423).

```php
/**
 * @param mixed $data
 */
function someMethod($data) {
   $data = (array) $data;
   // do your thing
}
```

If you work in Laravel, the [`Arr::wrap`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-wrap) method will handle this for you:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

/**
 * @param mixed $data
 */
function someMethod($data) {
   $data = Arr::wrap($data);
   // do your thing
}
```

However if it's not so generic and you want to ensure that it is only called with array params you could just have PHP enforce it by declaring a type before the argument.

```php
function someMethod(array $data) {
    // do your thing
}
```